# Cross origin request blocked for s3

Tags: javascript, django, amazon-s3, cross-domain, pre-signed-url

I have my pre-assigned URL and policy (created on django) for object to be uploaded into S3 directly from JavaScript. It works as expected during development and in local server. as soon as I upload to host and server online it give me the error of cross origin request blocked on Firefox and on chrome, it says that the request has been aborted. I have allowed all the domains to on bucket as well. I have even put the bucket public. below is my bucket policy and cors policy. I would be so happy for find a solution for this.

**Bucket Policy**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1621532678577",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::[bucketname]/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::[bucket-name]"
        ]
    }
```

**Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)**

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "PUT",
        "HEAD",
        "POST",
        "DELETE"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [
        "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
        "x-amz-request-id",
        "x-amz-id-2"
    ]
}
```

**JavaScript function**

```
 // auto-upload on file input change.
$(document).on('change','.cfeproj-upload-file', function(event){
    var selectedFiles = $(this).prop('files');
    formItem = $(this).parent()
    $.each(selectedFiles, function(index, item){
        var myFile = verifyFileIsImageMovieAudio(item)
        if (myFile){
          uploadFile(myFile)
        } else {
          alert("invalid file chosen.")
        }
    })
    $(this).val('');

})


function constructFormPolicyData(policyData, fileItem) {
   var contentType = fileItem.type != '' ? fileItem.type : 'application/octet-stream'
    var url = policyData.url
    var filename = policyData.filename
    var repsonseUser = policyData.user
    // var keyPath = 'www/' + repsonseUser + '/' + filename
    var keyPath = policyData.file_bucket_path
    var fd = new FormData()
    fd.append('key', keyPath + filename);
    fd.append('acl','private');
    fd.append('Content-Type', contentType);
    fd.append("AWSAccessKeyId", policyData.key)
    fd.append('Policy', policyData.policy);
    fd.append('filename', filename);
    fd.append('Signature', policyData.signature);
    fd.append('file', fileItem);
    return fd
}

function fileUploadComplete(js_profile){
    // get the new video url 
    // put the url on the vidoe tag
    // put a completed tag as
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        data: {js_profile:js_profile },
        url: "{% url 'start:upload_complete' %}",
        success: function(data){
          var vid_div = document.getElementsByClassName('js_profile_video')
          for(var i = 0; i < vid_div.length; i++){
            var nvid = document.createElement('video')
            nvid.controls = true
            nvid.muted = true
            nvid.setAttribute('width', '100%')
            // nvid.style.borderRadius = '10px'
            vid_div[i].innerHTML = ''
            vid_div[i].appendChild(nvid)
            addSourceToVideo(nvid, data, 'video/mp4');
            nvid.play();
          }
          var completed = $('#percentage_row')
          completed.html("")
          var htm = `<div class="center"><p class="green-text">your video is uploaded successfuly</p></div>`
          completed.append(htm)
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
            alert("An error occured, please refresh the page.")
        }
    })
}

function displayItems(fileItemList){
    var itemList = $('#percentage_row')
    itemList.html("")
    $.each(fileItemList, function(index, obj){
        var item = obj.file
        var id_ = obj.id
        var order_ = obj.order
        var html_ = "<div class=\"progress\">" + 
          "<div class=\"determinate\" style='width:" + item.progress + "%'></div></div>"
        itemList.append(html_)
    })
}

function uploadFile(fileItem){
    var policyData;
    var newLoadingItem;
    // get AWS upload policy for each file uploaded through the POST method
    // Remember we're creating an instance in the backend so using POST is
    // needed.
    js_profile = $('#js_job_profile').val()
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        data: { filename: fileItem.name, js_profile: js_profile },
        url: "{% url 'start:upload_policy' %}",
        success: function(data){ policyData = data },
        error: function(data){
            alert("An error occured, please try again later"+ data)
        }
    }).done(function(){
        // construct the needed data using the policy for AWS
        var fd = constructFormPolicyData(policyData, fileItem)
        // use XML http Request to Send to AWS. 
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        // construct callback for when uploading starts
        xhr.upload.onloadstart = function(event){
            var inLoadingIndex = $.inArray(fileItem, fileItemList)
            if (inLoadingIndex == -1){
                // Item is not loading, add to inProgress queue
                newLoadingItem = {
                    file: fileItem,
                    id: policyData.file_id,
                    order: fileItemList.length + 1
                }
                fileItemList.push(newLoadingItem)
                }
            fileItem.xhr = xhr
        }
        // Monitor upload progress and attach to fileItem.
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event){
            if (event.lengthComputable) {
                var progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
                fileItem.progress = progress
                displayItems(fileItemList)
            }
        })

        xhr.upload.addEventListener("load", function(event){
            console.log("Complete")
            fileUploadComplete(js_profile)
        })
        xhr.open('POST', policyData.url, true );
        xhr.send(fd);
    })
}});
// end of video upload module
```

Comment: CORS error is often shown when some other issue happens. Check if https request got anything back except the cors headers. Try using your "signed url" with something like postman to debug.